# Не обновляются данные в таблице

Tags: запрос, php, mysql

Здравствуйте, помогите решить проблему :( 
Проблема в следующем: почему то не обновляются данные в таблице :( что не так подскажите:(

```
    if($_GET['id']) {
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $news = $connect->real_query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '.$id.' ');
    $var = $connect->use_result();
    $row = $var->fetch_assoc();

}

$num = $row['view'];
$value = $num + 1;
$connect->real_query("UPDATE news SET view = '.$view.' WHERE id = '.$id.'");
```

Comment: если выполнить его из бд он выполнится
пример: 
UPDATE news SET view = 1 WHERE id = 1

Comment: так же самое странное если вот этот кусок кода убрать 
  if($_GET['id']) {
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $news = $connect->real_query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '.$id.' ');
    $var = $connect->use_result();
    $row = $var->fetch_assoc();

}

то будет работать

Comment: Где у Вас переменная "$id" объявлена? Наверное проблемы с областью видимости.

Comment: $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

со значениями все нормально я выводил их проверял через echo так что не в них проблема

Comment: errno показывает ошибку 2014

Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now 2014

Comment: Вы случайно не используете Codeigniter фреймворк в данном проекте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Проверяйте на существование, или не пустоту:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) { ... }
```

2) Переменной **$view** скорее всего не существует

```
$connect->real_query("UPDATE news SET view = '.$view.' WHERE id = '.$id.'");
```

3) Если php нормально работает, и просто не выполняется sql запрос, выводите ошибку у mysqli

4) У вас скорее всего не закрылся поток данных, после первого запроса. Надо либо насильно его закрыть, либо прочитать все данные.

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now 2014

```
// что-то вроде $var->close() или $var->free_result();
```

Comment: одна из проблем с $view :(  ну я исправил проблема осталась так же 

Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now 2014

Comment: спасибо! помогло $var->free_result();

Answer (score 0):

По логике вашего запроса у вас вместо $view должна быть $value

```
$connect->real_query("UPDATE news SET view = '.$value.' WHERE id = '.$id.'");
```

Также из oracle.com:

```
*Commands out of sync

 If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order.

 This can happen, for example, if you are using mysql_use_result() and try to execute a new query before you have called mysql_free_result(). It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data without calling mysql_use_result() or mysql_store_result() in between.*
```

Вкратце, вы вызываете mysql_use_result(), а затем пытаетесь выполнить запрос к БД без выполнения mysql_free_result().